# How to clear or regenerate window form after submitting using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, forms

I am using student record entry window form. I want that after submitting data, all fields of form(i.e radio button, combobox etc) and messages(warning and successful) should be reset so that new user can add data.

- is their any built in function to reset form in csharp?
- or I have to write clear method for this?
- or can I regenerate the form?

Comment: Instead of cleaning controls and starting a mess try using databinding instead.

Answer (score 13):

You must first clear the controls and then use `InitializeComponent` method to work perfectly.

```
this.Controls.Clear();
this.InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Comment: That's the easiest and perfect solution so far!

Answer (score 2):

This you can achieve in two ways:-

1) you can clear the fields of the form in one method. say `public void clear()` And whenever you want to clear the form simply call this method.

2) In second way you can destory the instance of the form and generate the new instance of the same form and then show this.

I will recomeded 1st one for you.

This is what I used to create in my every page

```
private void ClearControls()
{
    try
    {
        txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
        //txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
        txtFName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtMName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtLName.Text = string.Empty;
        lblUserType.Text = string.Empty;
    btnSave.Text = "Save";
    fnMessage(false, "");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    fnMessage(true, ex.Message);
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: This is poor mans way of doing things, try using databinding instead.

Comment: I'm not sure about this databinding. Can you please explain about how to do that.

Comment: Arjang can u explain databinding approach?

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement data binding to a given object ([good starting point here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/DataBinding_made_simple.aspx))
2. For resetting the form, create a new object and the binding will do it for you.

HTH

Comment: Databinding is only useful when your application lends itself to the solution. In my case, I have (min) 4 objects underneath my form, and the life of the objects does not map directly with that of the form. A neat solution if it fits, but there are plenty of reasons why it may not.

Comment: @CJM First, Databinding only saves you the code of mapping the form to the object (and vice versa). Second, what do display on the form if the life of the underlying object had already ended...?

Comment: @CJM : Please have a go at databinding, look at the link and give it a chance, it is the first step in writing n-tier. It would definitely worth your time I gaurentee it.

Comment: In my case there isn't an object - there are several, and in addition there is data from external equipment (PLC/Testing units/scanner etc). There are numerous controls that are updated according to external stimuli - most are not mapped to data we record, therefore not mapped to my DAL objects. Artificially creating objects just so we can databind to controls does not make sense in this scenario. Databinding is a useful approach, but it's not a 'one size fits all' approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can either re-create the form instance, or perhaps try something similar to this (untested):

```
        foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
        {
            switch (ctl.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "TextBox":
                    ctl.Text = null;
                    break;
                case "ComboBox":
                    ctl.Text = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Clearly, you can include as many different types of control as you wish and introduce other critieria (i.e. where control name begins with 'xyz' or where control resides within a particular panel).

Compared to other suggestions, the advantage of this approach is that if you have dozens of the same control type (typically textboxes), a few lines of code cover the lot. Additionally, if you add more controls of the covered types, you don't need to revisit the code to update it. Perhaps you could even create it as an extension method of your forms?

Answer (score 0):

Call `InitializeComponent` method and `Form_Load` method.

Comment: try it, you'll see that most things do not get cleared. ie. all fields without a values set in the InitializeComponents will remain as they were... try texting dfget into a textbox that is empty at form load :)

Comment: They will get cleared because new instances for all the controls are given in InitializeComponents method only

Comment: This is poor mans way of doing things, try using databinding instead.

Answer (score 0):

If form creation doesn't take too much resources it is easier to create new instance.

Comment: Why form creation where one can use databinding?

Answer (score 0):

As i had same problem and my from was having nested controls. I tried CJM's method and it worked however i had to write a recursive function because of controls nesting (tab controls, containers, user controls etc)

Try out the following snippet if you want to clear whole form recursively

```
    private void clearRecursive(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control subcontrol in control.Controls)
        {
            switch (subcontrol.GetType().ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Forms.", ""))
            {
                case "TextBox":
                    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)subcontrol;
                    textBox.Text = null;
                    break;

                case "ComboBox":
                    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)subcontrol;
                    if (comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
                        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    break;

                case "CheckBox":
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)subcontrol;
                    checkBox.Checked = false;
                    break;

                case "RadioButton":
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)subcontrol;
                    radioButton.Checked = false;
                    break;

                case "TreeView":
                    TreeView tv = (TreeView)subcontrol;
                    foreach (TreeNode node in tv.Nodes)
                    {
                        node.Checked = false;
                        CheckChildren(node, false);
                    }
                    break;

                case "ListBox":
                    ListBox listBox = (ListBox)subcontrol;
                    listBox.Items.Clear();
                    break;

                case "CheckedListBox":
                    CheckedListBox chklstbox = (CheckedListBox)subcontrol;
                    for (int i = 0; i < chklstbox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        chklstbox.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (subcontrol.HasChildren)
                clearRecursive(subcontrol);
        }

    }
```